# Polarising lens size for Nikon D7000

Tags: lens, filters, polarizer

I have a Nikon D7000 and need to buy a polarising lens but don't know what size lens I need. I have the the starter kit lens AF-S Nikkor 18-105mm1.35-5.6g ED. I'm new to photography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [18-105mm](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-105mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-ED-VR.html) has a filter size of 67mm.  So you need a 67mm polarising filter.